# How do you create non rectangular shaped image on website header/hero?

Tags: html, css, svg, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm creating a small website and i wanted to experiment with the modern non rectangular image approach on hero images, but i'm not sure how to go about it.Here is an example of what i'm trying to achieve.Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you've received so many down votes, but I know the solution to this. To achieve something like that type of design, you'll need to utilize an SVG. A Scale-able Vector Graphic(SVG) is an element in HTML used to draw a complex path, however many people utilize online tools pr programs like GIMP, Adobe Illustrator, or Inkscape to make them. You draw them in a program and export the path data to your HTML Document. I hope this helps you and your growing site.
https://inkscape.org/ -- Inkscape
https://www.gimp.org/ -- GIMP

Comment: Not very portable across older browsers though.

Comment: @RobC what is the best way to handle the older browser issues?

Comment: Dennis - Use progressive enhancement and consider creating a [SVG fallback](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-svg-fallbacks/) - which will entail detecting for SVG support and serving up methods such as [@ibra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55368336/how-do-you-create-non-rectangular-shaped-image-on-website-header-hero#answer-55368666) (or those mentions in the comments below it) when SVG is not supported by the browser. However, If you only care about [supporting modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=svg) then just use SVG.

Comment: @DennisGathagu In addition to what RobC is saying, you can save your SVG document that you crafted the banner with as an image. Images work in all browsers as far as I know. You can then dabble in responsive web design to get the same "scale-able" attributes as an SVG. I'd reccomend CSS-Tricks article on Responsive units in the link below. https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

Answer (score 1):

Use a png mask image on the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReAR9.png

```css
.wrap {position:relative;width:969px;height:300}
.wrap .bg {height:300px;background:url(https://images5.alphacoders.com/523/thumb-1920-523395.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;background-size:cover}
.wrap .mask {position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;height:74px;background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReAR9.png) no-repeat 0 0}
```

```html
<div style="width:969px;margin:0 auto">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="mask"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach is more  portable across older browsers than a SVG solution. However, you could just use one `.png` formatted hero image with a transparent cut-out (i.e. transparent where the curve is), instead of using a separate/additional image mask.

Comment: @RobC Yes, I agree. But some people can use this solution when they have a lot of main pictures or user uploaded images :)

Comment: I agree too. There's lots of pro's and cons with either your current solution or the approach I mentioned in my previous comment. For example using your current solution: **1)** If the background is not white (as per the OP) then a different colored mask is required to match the background color. **2)** Also, if the background is a repeated pattern or another image then a mask with a background pattern or matching image is necessary - alignment with repeated patterns then becomes difficult. (*1* and **2** are not an issue using the approach I mentioned in my previous comment -  btw: `[+1]`)

Comment: What's for certain though is your solution is more portable across older browsers than SVG. If the OP opts for the SVG approach they'll inevitably soon realize that they need to create a fallback using this method or similar - then they'll ask themselves why am I using the SVG solution at all ;)

Comment: @RobC so that really means using the SVG might be expensive to maintain in the long run?

Answer (score 0):

A great way to do that is with an SVG Clipping Path. This website here allows you to create the path you want and then it will automatically generate the CSS you need to create it.

https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Not very portable across older browsers though.

Comment: Yeah, then create the image like that in a photo editing program like photoshop.

Comment: Yep, that's typically what happens in the real world. i.e. Use the new shiny browser things --> client then tries it in an older browser --> then back to circa 2014 methods ;)

Comment: you'd probably think SVG being there for years shouldn't have browser compatibility issues